# Linking to front page GatsbyJS & WP REST API Menus

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, headless-cms

Every time I try to link to my front page on my Gatsby build it comes with an object slug which creates the wrong link in my menu. I have set the site to use a static front page in my WordPress settings so the front page shouldn't have a slug at all.

At the moment the front page link in my menu is testpage.local/frontpage which is wrong since there should be no slug. I have tried using direct url instead of object_slug but then the link is testpage.local/testpage.local/

I have also tried to create the menuitem is a custom link, but since it's linking to "/" it gets the same object_slug (frontpage).

Therefore, how can I use object_slug but telling WordPress that my front page is not having any slug?

The query I am using:

```
{
  allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems {
    edges {
      node {
        items {
          title
          object_slug
          url

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "items": [
              {
                "title": "Frontpage",
                "object_slug": "frontpage",
                "url": "/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Dummy page",
                "object_slug": "dummy-page",
                "url": "http://testpage.local/dummy-page/"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

creating the menu:

```
const MainMenu = () => (
  <StaticQuery query={graphql`{
        allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems {
          edges {
            node {
              items {
                title
                object_slug
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      `} render={props => (
      <div>
        {props.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(item => (
          <Link to={item.object_slug} key={item.title}>
            {item.title}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    )} />
);

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

Use `item.url` instead of `item.object_slug`

```js
{props.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(item => (
  <Link to={item.url} key={item.title}>
    {item.title}
  </Link>
))}
```

Then you need to install [gatsby-source-wordpress](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/) if you haven't already.

Finally, add this to your `gatsby-config.js`

```js
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
  options: {
    // your config...
    searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
    sourceUrl: "https://example.com", // WordPress URL
    replacementUrl: "http://localhost:3000", // Gatsby URL
    ,
  },
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but then my links are coming out like this: http://testpage.local/http://testpage.local/

Comment: Try to clear gatsby cache and rebuild. You need to restart the server on every `gatsby-config.js` change.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. The solution for me was to change the `replacementUrl: ""`.

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
  options: {
    // your config...
    searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
    sourceUrl: "https://example.com", // WordPress URL
    replacementUrl: "", // Gatsby URL
    ,
  },
}
```